# Android Studio 3.1.4 issues

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to AS and i'm having some teething issues.

I am following this tutorial with the kotlin path
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/

I am getting these errors when attempting to run the app

> e: C:\Users\Dan\Downloads\Whackamole-Making-toast-v1.0\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\dan\myfirstapp\DisplayMessageActivity.kt: (19, 52): Unresolved reference: textView
>
> e: C:\Users\Dan\Downloads\Whackamole-Making-toast-v1.0\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\dan\myfirstapp\MainActivity.kt: (20, 22): Expression 'intent' of type 'Intent!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
>
> e: C:\Users\Dan\Downloads\Whackamole-Making-toast-v1.0\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\dan\myfirstapp\MainActivity.kt: (21, 13): Unresolved reference: putExtra

As far as I can tell I have entered the code exactly as it should be. Any help is greatfully appreciated

EDIT: Heres the code

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.dan.myfirstapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
fun sendMessage(view: View) {
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
    val message = editText.text.toString()
    val intent = intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

**activity_display_message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**DisplayMessageActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.dan.myfirstapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)


    //Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    //Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as it's text
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
        text = message
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not helping. If you could post your code, probably we could help you.
Unresolved reference: textView :- looks like textView is not declared properly

Comment: It's better to provide the code you have written instead of the tutorial link, tutorials don't help to resolve issues in your code.

Comment: Sorry. Code added

Answer (score 2):

1. `textView` does not exist in `activity_display_message.xml`
2. `val intent = Intent(..)`
   instead of `val intent = intent(..)`

For the 1st: place a `TextView` with id `textView` in `activity_display_message.xml`  
For the 2nd: you instantiate the variable `intent` as an instance of the class `Intent`.

Edit: I found the lesson you're working on and I see that you missed the part with the title: 
"Add a text view"

Comment: Ahh thank you! I didn't miss the text view part but I added a plain text instead. Could you please explain the part about intent in more depth?

Comment: Thank you! Changing the ID to `textView` did the trick for me.